# RSpec: how can I spy on interactions with an existing object?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have an existing stub object, that I am using as a collaborator in my tests:

```
cf_client = Aws::CloudFormation::Client.new(:stub_responses => true)
stack = described_class.new("name", cf_client)
```

The stub object (`cf_client`) was *not* created using rspec-mocks; it's a fake implementation provided by the `aws-sdk` gem, and has useful properties.

However, it doesn't provide message verification, so I am hoping to wrap in a proxy that records the received messages, so I can verify them later, while still delegating to the wrapped object, e.g.

```
cf_client = proxy_spy(Aws::CloudFormation::Client.new(:stub_responses => true))
stack = described_class.new("name", cf_client)

stack.create

expect(cf_client).to have_received(:create_stack)
```

Want I want/need is the `proxy_spy` method. Does something like this exist? Can I use RSpec's verifying proxies here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`and_call_original`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation).

```
cf_client = Aws::CloudFormation::Client.new(:stub_responses => true)
expect(cf_client).to_receive(:create_stack).and_call_original
stack = described_class.new("name", cf_client)
stack.create
```